# Return type error while building a C-based project with Android-NDK (Clang)

Tags: c, android-ndk, clang

I'm trying to build **CHOLMOD library** (a part of [suitesparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html)) for Android. This library uses a Makefile based build system and I am trying to use CMake.

Now `t_cholmod_triplet.c` is a part of the library and defines a function in the following way :

```
#include "cholmod_template.h"
#include "cholmod_core.h"
#include "cholmod_internal.h"

static size_t TEMPLATE (cholmod_triplet_to_sparse)
(
    /* ---- input ---- */
    cholmod_triplet *T, /* matrix to copy */
    /* ---- in/out --- */
    cholmod_sparse *R,  /* output matrix */
    /* --------------- */
    cholmod_common *Common
)
{
    double *Rx, *Rz, *Tx, *Tz ;
    Int *Wj, *Rp, *Ri, *Rnz, *Ti, *Tj  ;
    Int i, j, p, p1, p2, pdest, pj, k, stype, nrow, ncol, nz ;
    size_t anz ;
    ...
    ... Computations
    ... 
    return (anz)
}
```

When I try to build, clang complains the following :

```
error: function cannot return function type 'size_t (cholmod_triplet *, cholmod_sparse *, cholmod_common *)' (aka 'unsigned int (struct cholmod_triplet_struct *, struct cholmod_sparse_struct *, struct cholmod_common_struct *)')
```

From the last line in the above function, it is returning a type `size_t`. But Clang is thinking it is returning a function (error description). What is the reason for this? and What minimal changes would correct this error?

### Edit-1

After doing a clean project and rebuild, now I'm getting error with `t_cholmod_dense.c` [link to file](https://github.com/cusoh/chomlod_temp/blob/master/t_cholmod_dense.c)

The error footprint is similar, return type is being perceived incorrectly:

```
error: function cannot return function type 'cholmod_dense *(cholmod_sparse *, cholmod_common *)' (aka 'struct cholmod_dense_struct *(struct cholmod_sparse_struct *, struct cholmod_common_struct *)')
```

### Edit-2

```
#include "cholmod_core.h"
#include "cholmod_internal.h"
#include "cholmod_template.h"

static void TEMPLATE (change_simplicial_numeric)
(
    cholmod_factor *L,
    Int to_ll,
    Int to_packed,
    Int *newLi,
    double *newLx,
    double *newLz,
    Int lnz,
    Int grow,
    double grow1,
    Int grow2,
    Int make_ll,
    Int make_monotonic,
    Int make_ldl,
    cholmod_common *Common
)
{
```

Throws the following error:

```
app/src/main/cpp/include/CHOLMOD/Core/t_cholmod_change_factor.c:23:22: error: function cannot return function type 'void (cholmod_factor *, int, int, int *, double *, double *, int, int, double, int, int, int, int, cholmod_common *)' (aka 'void (struct cholmod_factor_struct *, int, int, int *, double *, double *, int, int, double, int, int, int, int, struct cholmod_common_struct *)')
```

Comment: I think we might have to know what `TEMPLATE` expands to in order to help with this?

Comment: @SteveFriedl Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with such a usage (with run-time type change). [Here](https://github.com/cusoh/chomlod_temp/blob/master/cholmod_template.h) is a link to the relevant file cholmod_template.h

Comment: Ok, can you please show the #include files at the top of the file that this is part of? I'm almost sure you're missing a file.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I have added the `#include` directives. Also added an update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this package, but it's clear that there is some macro stuff going on that's not being handled properly.

The `TEMPLATE()` macro is found in the #include file you mentioned, and there's a long series of `#ifdef`s that transform it into some other related macro that attempts to rename the function with a prefix:

```
R_TEMPLATE(myfunction) --> r_myfunction
P_TEMPLATE(myfunction) --> p_myfunction
CT_TEMPLATE(myfunction) --> ct_myfunction
C_TEMPLATE(myfunction)  --> c_myfunction
ZT_TEMPLATE(myfunction) --> zt_myfunction
Z_TEMPLATE(myfunction)  --> z_myfunction
```

These second level macros appear to be defined in `include/cholmod_complexity.h`, which is in turn included by `include/cholmod_internal.h`.

EDIT: You just updated your question, and that explains  everything.

```
#include "cholmod_template.h"  // move me last
#include "cholmod_core.h"
#include "cholmod_internal.h"
```

The template part needs to come *after* the internal, so move it after the `cholmod_internal.h` include file. Then, when the template macros invoke `R_TEMPLATE` or whatever, they find those definitions found in `cholmod_internal.h`

Comment: Your suggestion worked for those two files. I still have the similar error on some other files (even after modifying the `#include` order). I am exploring what could be wrong. Thank you so much for this helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your second example, it's clear that it's related. The error is:

```
app/.../Core/t_cholmod_change_factor.c:23:22: error: function cannot return function type 

'void (cholmod_factor *, int, int, int *, double *, double *, int, int, double, int, int, int, int, cholmod_common *)'
```

(I removed the "aka" part of the error.  This is basically the function definition but removing the name:

```
void NAMEGOESHERE (cholmod_factor *, ... );
```

so it's obviously failing to compile.

Is the makefile building all the files with the same compiler flags / macro definitions? It might be that there is a path through the various #include files that somehow fails to define a `TEMPLATE` macro, so the compiler sees no function name.

Thought: Add this after your #includes but before the function:

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE
#  error "We don't have a TEMPLATE macro - why is that?"
#endif
```

This way, if for whatever reason there's a missing macro, it lets you know directly rather than via the mysterious and unhelpful compiler warning.

Comment: I applied the said lines and the error is thrown by this file **t_cholmod_triplet.c** file [triplet file](https://github.com/cusoh/chomlod_temp/blob/master/t_cholmod_triplet.c)

Comment: This means the file is probably not being built the same way that the other ones are. Are the compiler flags the same for the ones you fixed versus this one?

Comment: I am using CMake to build the project. You can see the CMakeLists.txt file [here](https://github.com/cusoh/chomlod_temp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). I believe the compiler flags should be same.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know CMake, and I don't see any compiler flags *at all*.  If you run cmake, does it show you all the command lines being run? Do you see a difference in any compiler flags between the various files?

Comment: I saw your edit showing the command line with the failure. Can you show the same command line for a compile that works OK?  It would be a surprise to me if these did not all build the same way, but I don't know.

Comment: I think the error might be because of the ordering in which I have placed the files in my CMakeLists.txt      I will take a look at the original Makefile and try to order these source files in same order and then come back with my observation. Thank you so much for devoting your time for my case. Regards